# GDrive calculates matrix multiplications differently in GSheets and . xlsx. Does anyone know why this is?

Tags: microsoft-excel, browser, google-spreadsheets

I've been using Google Forms and Google Sheets to gather and analyze data for some time. I use array formulas and calculate matrix multiplications. For back-up reasons, I had to export the Sheet as .xlsx. When I opened the .xlsx on Drive to check if everything work alright, I realized that the two documents give different results to the same matrix multiplication.

Here is the formula that I use in Gsheets, which gives "33.65384615"

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(N(EH2:ET),sequence(COLUMNS(EH2:ET),1)^0)-13)/13*25/2
```

And this is the formula exported to .xlsx which gives "35,5"

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(N(EH2:ET102);sequence(COLUMNS(EH2:ET102);1)^0)-13/13*25/2); 101; 1)
```

Does anyone know the reason behind this? And if/how it can be fixed?

Comment: According to the tag excerpt of [tag:google-drive] this tag should be used for questions about an installable client that is now deprecated. Google Drive on the web doesn't do spreadsheet calculations. You should [edit] the question to mention what  Google Drive app or what web browser extension are using to open Excel files. That app or extension is the one that does the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. It's because .xlsx forgot a parenthesis after `-13` in the second formula. It's fixed once I wrote it like this:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA((MMULT(N(EH2:ET102);sequence(COLUMNS(EH2:ET102);1)^0)-13)/13*25/2); 101; 1)
```

Comment: Be careful when using Google Sheets / Google Drive to edit Excel files if you plan that those files be opened using Excel because functions like ARRAY_CONSTRAIN aren't supported by Excel. Ref. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-functions-alphabetical-b3944572-255d-4efb-bb96-c6d90033e188